# Illiterate connectwall

Tags: word, knowledge, connect-wall

The words here can be grouped into four groups. The groups taken together will hint at a 7 letter word. Good Luck!

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RANGE | FRO | HANG | ASP |
| WHITE | WIND | SNAP | LOCK |
| LEGO | LAN | AND | BARB |
| SCRUB | THROAT | MAN | EASE |

Small Hint:

> Yes the Title gives a clue where to start!!

Comment: Think I have 3 of the 4 categories but can't pinpoint the fourth - can I ask: Are all 4 of these *categories* widely known? (If my hunches are right this far, I would say 2 of *them* definitely are, and the other 1 I think I've found is perhaps a little more niche, which is why I'm doubting it...)

Comment: Well one of them is a little niche if you are not a brit...

Comment: If you have found the general theme a little google search will solve it for you.

Comment: Anyway going to head off so good luck!!

Comment: Ok, I would say that what I'd call my 'D' group may be the niche UK-centred one... Placing EASE will be key to my remaining group I reckon... Will only post if I can nail it down...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This Connecting Wall is all about:

> Characters from series of **FANTASY** books - 'Illiterate' in the title is a nod towards *literature*.
>
>  Each of these 16 words appears as a substring within the name of a character from the *[Harry Potter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter)* series, *[The Lord of the Rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings)*, Terry Pratchett's *[Discworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discworld)* novels, or *[The Chronicles of Narnia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Narnia)*.

The groups:

> **Group 1: Harry Potter character surnames**
>  G**RANGE**R, C**HANG**, **SNAP**E, and possibly a misspelling of W**EAS**(E)LEY.
>
>  **Group 2: LoTR characters**
>  **LEGO**LAS, **FRO**DO, G**AND**ALF, SARU**MAN**.
>
>  **Group 3: Discworld characters**
>  RINCE**WIND**, Cut-Me-Own-**THROAT** Dibbler, Cohen the **BARB**ARIAN, Lord Have**LOCK** Vetinari.
>
>  **Group 4: Chronicles of Narnia characters**
>  AS**LAN**, C**ASP**IAN, **SCRUB**B, The **WHITE** Witch.

Comment: This looks good. I've read all of the books of group 4 and can't even remember most of the characters you've mentioned, I wonder if there is another series that would work?

Comment: Well done! You have 3 groups right... But the last I am afraid is wrong also in the first group you have one wrong and third, you have couple wrong.

Comment: Hint: The writer was also religious.

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker Okay, I've had a second attempt - pretty sure all categories are right (though not necessarily their members of course), but this classification depends on there being a typo in your wall. I hope I'm wrong about that?!

Comment: Yes although it is Lord Havelock Vetinari.